# I want to know that After making GUI in Glade where actually "c" file generate?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, glade

I am working with C GUI using GTK+3.0 library.and i am using tool Glade i want to know that after making GUI in Glade where actually "c" file generate for that GUI.

Comment: It saves source code into the project directory. As mentioned here "http://www.togaware.com/linux/survivor/Build_Source.html"

Comment: In project directory .c file save or .glade file?

Comment: It should be .c file because .glad file is always project file. go into your tools menu and general and see if you can find directory references to your generated code.

Comment: Glade-3 does not generate a .c file that can be compiled. It generates a .glade which is an XML file describing the layout of the widgets and what signals to connect. You load this file at run time into your program to create the widgets.  Very very old versions did generate .c files but that was a long time ago.

Comment: You should make that into the answer.

Comment: Please you tell me that in which version of glade generate ".c" file? @Errolvandel'Isle

Comment: @MayankPatel The last version that I can find for Glade that supports generating a compilable ".c" file is version 0.5.11 released in October 2000 and there is no support for it. The code it generates would only be compatible with GTK+ 1.2 again not supported and since you are using GTK+ version 3 **it will not work** as the widgets are now very different.

Comment: Thank You..!!@Errolvandel'Isle

Answer (score 3):

Glade-3 does not generate a .c file that can be compiled. It generates a .glade (.ui) which is an XML file describing the layout of the widgets and what signals to connect. You load this file at run time into your program to create the widgets. Very very old versions did generate .c files but that was a long time ago.

Most of the functions that you need to use in your application to use the Glade file are based on GtkBuilder and the functions starting with gtk_builder_*(). The API documentation is at https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html.

An example test.c program :-

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#define UI_FILE "test.ui"
#define WIDGET_WINDOW "a_window"

/* Callback for the buttons */
void on_button_clicked (GtkButton* button,
                        gpointer user_data)
{
  gtk_main_quit();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkBuilder *builder;

  /* Initialize gtk+*/
  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  builder = gtk_builder_new ();
  gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, UI_FILE, NULL);

  window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, WIDGET_WINDOW));
  gtk_builder_connect_signals (builder, NULL);
    
  gtk_widget_show (window);

  gtk_main ();
  return 0;
}
```

Its corresponding Glade file test.ui

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="a_window">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="vexpand">True</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">label</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Close</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_button_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```